# Scale ellipsoid maximally within polyhedron

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, polyhedra, ellipsoids

Given an ellipsoid around the origin with scaling parameter $e$ in the form $x^T E x \leq e$ and a polyhedron $P$ given by $A x \leq b$, how can we define an optimization problem that maximizes e such that the ellipsoid is fully contained in $P$? Note that $E$ is constant, i.e. the problem is not the same as inscribing an ellipsoid of maximal volume into a polyhedron. Moreover, $A$, $b$ are constant as well.

My basic idea would be as follows. The ellipsoid equation can be rewritten as $x^T \frac{1}{e} E x \leq 1$. Let $F = \frac{1}{e} E$. Let $U$ be the matrix with columns being the eigenvectors of $F$ which is equal to the eigenvectors of $E$, i.e. $U$ is constant. Let $V$ be the diagonal matrix with $\sqrt{\lambda_i}$ on the diagonal where $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to the $i$-th row of $U$. Note that $v_{i,i}$ is of the form $\sqrt{\frac{const}{e}}$. We can rewrite the ellipsoid equation as $x = U V^{-1} z$, $\|z\| \leq 1$. Then the optimization problem over the single variable $e$ becomes:

$\max \log(\det(U V^{-1}))$ where $\|U V^{-1} a_i^T\| \leq b_i ~ \forall i$ ($a_i$ denotes the $i$-th row of A)

Do you agree with this approach? Is there a simpler way to represent the original problem?

Comment: Mathabc: including $x\geq0$ in $P$ guarantees that $e=0$.

Comment: Ops, you are right. I removed the constraint $x \geq 0$. Could you please enable the question again?

Comment: There is definitely a simpler way. You can solve the single-inequality case with a very simple constrained optimization. Then the full case just takes the minimum of those. I believe you get $e=\min_i b_i^2/(a_i^TE^{-1}a_i)$ when everything is nice and clean, but you can work out the nonsingular and infeasible cases too.

Comment: It seems you transformed the problem into an unconstrained optimization problem but I fail to see why this works. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: No, a set of constrained problems, actually. If they re-open the question... ;-)

Comment: Your rewrite doesn't accomplish what you hope anyway. You still have $n$ degrees of freedom, one for each eigenvalue. Your original problem has a single degree of freedom---$e$.

Comment: In my attempt there is only one variable, namely $e$, i.e. $A, E, b$ are constant. Thus, $U, V$ contain only one variable as well. Nevertheless, it appears unnecessarily cumbersome.

Comment: That's not well reflected in the description of your problem. $e$ doesn't even appear in your optimization problem. What are the problem variables?

Comment: $A, E, b$ are constant. The single problem variable is $e$. This variable occurs in $U, V$.

Comment: But *how* exactly does it "occur" in U, V? It simply isn't specified.

Comment: I have to correct myself. $e$ only occurs in $V$ since the eigenvectors of $\frac{1}{e} E$ are equal to those of $E$, i.e. $U$ is constant. The elements of the diagonal matrix $V$ should be of the form $\sqrt{\frac{const}{e}}$.

Comment: Then put that *in the model*. Edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: Can you do a trivial edit to this question? I accidentally downvoted and can't change that until you edit.

Comment: I did a trivial edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the full [convex optimization machinery](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/examples/cvxbook/Ch08_geometric_probs/html/max_vol_ellip_in_polyhedra.html) normally applied to this problem. But if even if you wanted to use convex optimization, your ellipsoid parameterization isn't compatible with it. That parameterization works with *minimum*-volume ellipsoids, not *maximum*. To do volume maximization you need to work with $B=E^{-1/2}$.

Fortunately, you don't even need to do that.

First of all, note that if any element of $b$ is negative, no ellipsoid of any volume exists, because even $x=0$ is not in the polyhedron. So we will assume henceforth that $b\succeq 0$. We will also assume that none of the rows of $A$ are zero, though we could handle that case with a bit of care below.

Let's look at a single inequality $a_i^Tx\leq b_i$. The minimum $e$ is given by
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & e = x^T E x \\
\text{subject to} & a_i^T x = b_i
\end{array}
In other words, we want the smallest ellipsoid that touches the hyperplane that separates the halfspaces. This is convex and readily solved with a Lagrangian approach. The Lagrangian and corresponding optimality conditions are
$$L(x,\lambda)=x^TEx+\lambda(b_i-a_i^Tx) \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
2Ex = \lambda a_i, ~ a_i^Tx=b$$
In the likely event that $E$ is full rank (i.e., positive definite), then
$x=\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda E^{-1}a_i$, so $\lambda$ can be determined by
$$a_i^Tx = \tfrac{1}{2}\lambda a_i^TE^{-1}a_i = b_i \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\lambda = 2b_i/(a_i^TE^{-1}a_i)$$
Therefore,
$$e=x^TEx=\tfrac{1}{4}\lambda^2 a_i^TE^{-1}a_i = b_i^2/(a_i^TE^{-1}a_i).$$
To solve for the multiple inequalities, we simply need the *smallest* value of $e$ from the bunch:
$$e = \min_i b_i^2/(a_i^TE^{-1}a_i).$$
As a sanity check, note that if $a_i$ and $b$ are scaled by the same positive value, $e$ does not change. This is exactly what we would expect, because the hyperplane doesn't move.

In the event that $E$ is *not* full rank, then you have a bit more work to do. For brevity I'll offer the result below, but can offer more derivation if requested.
$$e = \begin{cases} 0 & \exists i ~ a_i \not\in\mathop{\textrm{Range}}(E) \\
\min_i b_i^2/(a_i^TE^\dagger a_i) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
where $E^\dagger$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $E$.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation. Could you give me a hint how you derive that $e=0$ if $E$ is not positive definite?

Comment: It's not *necessarily* zero unless $a_i\not\in\mathop{\textrm{Range}}(A)$. Look at the Lagrangian optimality condition $2Ex=\lambda a_i$ again. In that particular case, the only way you can solve this optimality condition is if $Ex=0$ and $\lambda=0$.

Comment: I see now, thanks. There is a small typo in your comment: should be $a_i \notin \text{Range}(E)$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, your suggested edit to the post itself was incorrect. $E^{-1}$ does not exist in the rank deficient case. $E^\dagger$ refers to the pseudoinverse, as I have clarified.